# Redis sentinel - duplicate error - dup-sentinel messages

Tags: redis

I'm using Redis-x64-3.0.504 for windows and I have configured three servers: Master1, Slave1 and Slave2.

I've started sentinel with this config in EACH one:

```
sentinel monitor mymaster 1.1.1.1 6379 2
```

1.1.1.1 is the Master1 IP address.

Here is a warning I'm constantly getting:

```
[5832] 24 Aug 12:41:49.608 * -dup-sentinel master mymaster 1.1.1.1 6379 #
duplicate of 1.1.1.2:26379
```

1.1.1.2 is Slave2 IP address.

Actually, this message is thrown again and again exactly when I start the master sentinel (while the other slaves sentinels are running).

Any help ?

**EDITED:**
I've encountered this question:
[redis 2.8.7 sentinel environment configuration questions for linux, how to make it autostart, what they should subscribe to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22641487/redis-2-8-7-sentinel-environment-configuration-questions-for-linux-how-to-make)

One responded that you shouldn't run senitnel on master but that's not what I've read in the docs.

Comment: It's talking about the sentinel gossip protocol encountering a partial match of a sentinel by it's runid+ip+port combination. This means one of the sentinels probably restarted with a new runid (did it?) and its warning about that state change in the log.

Comment: @nnog 
runid- I didn't configure it in config files so that should be generated automatically.
ip - It's a different ip to each one, but in sentinel.conf of each server I've configured this : sentinel monitor mymaster 1.1.1.1 6379 2 .
port - I've used the same sentinel port in each one: 26379

Comment: Well each sentinel's runid is generated anew when it starts up, so if one of your sentinels was restarted, you should expect the `duplicate of` warning in the logs of the other sentinels, since they announce their presence to eachother through the master instance.

Comment: @nnog I don't understand. I'm getting those "duplicate" messages again and again.. this warning doesn't stop in slaves and the config file of slaves sentinel get updated every sec.. runids are different from each other

Comment: If the runids are changing all the time, then maybe you are auto restarting crashing sentinels? Your link to the other SO question suggests you might be doing some kind of auto restart.

Comment: @nnog no I don't. I just start them on each node (including the master).. their not crashing.. 
If I do NOT run the master's sentinel - everything seems to work fine but I know that doesn't suppose to be like that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121847/discussion-between-nnog-and-ohadinho).